# Função javascript duplicando disparo pelo método init

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função no meu menu principal que, quando clicada, inicia um `'classe'` para o setor em questão, tudo ocorre bem, porém, eu preciso iniciar a mesma classe novamente quando alguém volta para o setor, e nisso, os métodos tem sua chamada duplicada, segue exemplo:

```js
var Collaborators = function () {
    var open_collab_editor = function(){

    $(document).on('click', '.edit-collaborator', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('fui chamado')
    });

    }
    return {
        init: function () {
            open_collab_editor();
        }
    };
}();


$(document).on('click', '.abrir', function (e) {
    console.log('inciado');
    Collaborators.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='abrir'>Setor x</button>

<button class='edit-collaborator'>Editar (Função iniciada pelo Setor x)</button>
```

Veja que cada vez que clico em `'Setor x'` ele aumenta o numero de vezes que a função `'open_collab_editor()'` é chamada, isso que eu quero impedir e não estou conseguindo, preciso destruir a primeira iniciação pra poder iniciar de novo, ou outra forma de fazer isso.

Não posso permitir que o evento que é disparado em `'open_collab_editor()'` possa ser disparado antes de clicar em `'setor x'`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que a acada chamada da função "iniciado" você esta **adicionando** na lista de eventos do elemento ".edit-collaborator" uma nova chamada.
Pense em um *array* com a lista de todas as chamadas para este elemento, basicamente você esta sempre adicionando. e não sobrescrevendo.

Para resolver isso sera necessário usar o [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), assim você remove da pilha para então adicionar. Assim removendo a duplicidade.

```js
var Collaborators = function () {

    function handler2(e){ // Aqui você nomeia a função para poder remover ela
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('fui chamado')
    }

    var open_collab_editor = function(){
    
        // Remove o evento
        $(document).off('click', '.edit-collaborator', handler2);
        // Adiciona o evento
        $(document).on('click', '.edit-collaborator', handler2);
    }
    
    // Se você sempre vai fazer Collaborators.init() basta retornar direto a função e fazer Collaborators()
    return open_collab_editor;
}();

$(document).on('click', '.abrir', function(e){
    console.log('inciado');
    Collaborators();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='abrir'>Setor x</button>

<button class='edit-collaborator'>Editar (Função iniciada pelo Setor x)</button>
```

#### Nota

Aqui eu decidi nomear a função de dentro para remover exclusivamente ela, apontando ele no `.off`, se eu fizer simplesmente `.off('click', elemente)` vai remover todas as chamadas, mesmo de outras funções.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa remover a função que está no clique em `.edit-collaborator`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-collaborator', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('fui chamado')
});
```

Deveria ser:

```
$(document).off("click", ".edit-collaborator").on('click', '.edit-collaborator', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('fui chamado')
});
```